# Laravel blade: How do you delete prepoulated form field data (save in db as null)

Tags: database, forms, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I'm building some forms where fields are populated with database data or defaults to Placeholder text if there is no data.

What I can't seem to figure out is: When a user deletes all data in form it wont save it back to the database as blank/null, it just carried the same value in the field...

Input:

```
<div class="form-group @if($errors->has('username')){{ 'has-error' }}@endif">    
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        @if($errors->has('username'))<span class="label-has-error">{{ $errors->first('username') }}</span>@endif
        <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" tabindex="1" @if($info->username) value="{{ e($info->username) }}" @else placeholder="Username" @endif>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
public function postSettings() {

    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(),
        array(
            'username' => 'required_without_all:location,fullname|min:3',
            'fullname' => 'required_without_all:location,username',
            'location' => 'required_without_all:fullname,username'
        )
    );

    if($validator->fails()) {

        return Redirect::route('settings')->withErrors($validator);

    } else {

        $user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);

        if(Input::get('username')) {
            $user->username = Input::get('username');
        }
        if(Input::get('fullname')) {
            $user->fullname = Input::get('fullname');
        }
        if(Input::get('location')) {
            $user->location = Input::get('location');
        }

        $user->save();

        Flash::success('Settings have been updated');

        return Redirect::route('settings');

    }

    Flash::error('Update was unsecessful, please try again!');

    return Redirect::route('settings');

}
```

Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Thanks, Jack.

Comment: It's hard to say anything without your code. It's your job to save data to database in controller. You should provide controller code

Comment: Hi @MarcinNabiałek I've added the controller code in. I'm not sure what the logic is to detect if the form is empty. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem are `if` statements.

You should try to change:

```
if(Input::get('username')) {
    $user->username = Input::get('username');
}
if(Input::get('fullname')) {
    $user->fullname = Input::get('fullname');
}
if(Input::get('location')) {
    $user->location = Input::get('location');
}
```

into

```
$user->username = Input::get('username');
$user->fullname = Input::get('fullname');
$user->location = Input::get('location');
```

Now if those inputs are empty `if` statement will return false, so assignment won't be done and finally you save into database exactly you got from it.

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly. I always forget how simple things are with Laravel :)